# How do i fix this Eevee rendering Problem?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I can notfix this issue when selecting Eevee for my renders.
It gets really annoying. I can get rid of them temporary when I scroll out or into the viewport.
Does anyone have an Idea how I can fix that?

thanks c:

[image: Help!]

Comment: I've literally never seen that before in Eevee. What GPU are you using?

Comment: OpenCL -> AMD Radeon RX 5700